# Owl.carousel.min.js Routed Page Reload on Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, owl-carousel

I working on an Angular project and using a template. My template uses owl.carousel.min.js. My problem that routed page resize and reload after routing when i clicked any menu button. I don't want to reload page when routing.

index.html
...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js'><\/script>
```

home.component.html

```
 <ul id="menu-important-links" class="menu rt-mega-menu-transition-slide">
     <li id="menu-item-222" class="home-megamenu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom rt-mega-menu-full-width rt-mega-menu-hover item-222">
         <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/">{{ 'Home' | translate }}</a>
     </li>           
     <li id="menu-item-711" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-flyout rt-mega-menu-hover item-711">
         <a routerLink="/contactus" > {{ 'Contact' | translate }}</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

app-routing-module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
   { path: 'contactus', component: ContactComponent }
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: Post some code and what all have your tried so far.

Comment: Also, if possible, create a StackBlitz project!

Comment: I added some code.

Comment: @İsmailKasap which version of angular you are using?  angularjs(1.x.x) or angular(2/4/5/6)

Comment: @Sanoj_V I use angular 5

Answer (score 1):

Use `routerLink` instead of `href`. href would reload the page. So get rid of it. And use `routerLink` which is a special directive that comes with `RouterModule`. It works similar to an href with the difference that it doesn't reload the page.

So replace this `<a href="#">{{'Home' | translate}}</a>`. with `<a routerLink="/home">{{'Home' | translate}}</a>`

Then try changing the sequence of your route config.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
   { path: 'contactus', component: ContactComponent },
   { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Here's a [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sample-routing-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) for your reference.

Also, you shouldn't add third-party scripts directly in your index.html file like you've done here. Instead, you should add them to the `scripts` array of `.angular-cli.json` or `angular.json`

Comment: ah sorry my mistake. I have been added wrong part of my code. I edited and problem is continuing.

Comment: Please add a StackBliz.com project replicating the issue that you're getting. It's really hard to figure out what the issue actually is.